# How do I check if collection contains an object with a specific key in handlebars

Tags: bigcommerce

Assuming custom_fields contains this data, and I want to find out if it has an item/object with the name = "hide_options". I want to pass this to a component.

> WARNING
>   Using occurrences in this way is a **hack**. If the **name** isn't unique enough, you may get false-positives

```
[
  {"id":"12","name":"hide_options","value":"true"}, 
  {"id":"13","name":"state","value":"colorado"},
  {"id":"14","name":"city","value":"colorado, springs"}
]
```

The closest I've come up with is this:

**templates\components\products\product-view.html**

```
{{> components/products/conditionallyVisibile 
    hideOptions=(occurrences (join (pluck product.custom_fields "name") ",") "hide_options") 
}}
```

**components/products/conditionallyVisibile.html**

```
<div>
    hideOptions {{ hideOptions }}
</div>
```

Am I missing an easier Array or Collection helper that would make this easier? Most of the Array/Collection helpers are block helpers.

EDIT:
I was missing a significantly easier way to do this via the [Filter Array Helper](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/handlebars-syntax-and-helpers/handlebars-helpers-reference/array-helpers/standard-array-helpers#handlebars_filter)

```
{{#filter product.custom_fields "hide_options" property="name"}}
    {{> components/products/conditionallyVisibile hideOptions=true }}
{{else}}
    {{> components/products/conditionallyVisibile hideOptions=false }}
{{/filter}}
```

---

EDIT 2:

the scalar-form of

`(occurrences (join (pluck product.custom_fields "name") ",") "hide_options")`

is almost-equivalent to the block-form

`{{#inArray (pluck product.custom_fields 'name') 'hide_options' }}`

Comment: Hey @JJS, I think the way you are doing this is the best option for the time being. You're correct, most of the array/collection helpers are block helpers. This kind of query should be a lot more straightforward once we have the GraphQL storefront API in place later this year.

Comment: This approach illustrates the difference between "technology you know" vs "technology you love". I'm going to do a pull request to the paper-helpers `containsKey(array object-key search-value) returns bool`
I get so spoiled by underscore.js, and Linq in C#, and when I can't query a data context easily in a template language it makes me sad/angry.

Comment: That's an understandable point of view--we'd like this to be easier too. Thanks for taking on a pull request. We'll make sure it gets reviewed right away

Comment: @KarenWhite added an example using the #filter helper.

Comment: I like that! Clever to use a block helper to switch the parameter passed to the component.